# GetProfileDocument cause File does not exist in lotuscript after switch ID

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

After switching ID, a user started to get error "File does not exist (CN=*user_name*/O=*Organization*) on the GetProfileDocument. Did someone already experienced such trouble?

After cleaning cache.ndk, it seems to be solved. Would you advice to re install the client ?

Below the function:

```
Function getUserProfile() As NotesDocument
On Error GoTo handlErr

Static docUserProfile As NotesDocument
If docUserProfile Is Nothing Then
    Dim dbCurrent As NotesDatabase
    Dim s As New NotesSession
    Set dbCurrent = s.CurrentDatabase
    Set docUserProfile  = dbCurrent.GetProfileDocument(s.EffectiveUserName )        
End If
Set getUserProfile = docUserProfile

Exit Function
handlErr:
If s Is Nothing Then Set s = New NotesSession
LogError("s.EffectiveUserName="+s.EffectiveUserName)
Exit Function
End Function
```

thx in advance

Comment: It is unusual to have a profile with the username as "ProfileName". More common would be something like `Set docUserProfile  = dbCurrent.GetProfileDocument( "UserProfile", s.EffectiveUserName )`. But I'm not sure, if this is the cause for your problem...

Comment: Thank you @Torsten, this code works for years, but I agree the use of uniqueKey in place of profilename may have avoid problem to occurs. But even like this this is a strange issue, some of my users switch regulary ids (shared PC) and never got such error.

Comment: Does client restart combined with ID switching help? If so, it maybe some caching issue.

Comment: Thank you @FrantisekKossuth, yes I also restarted the client, and cleaned up cache.ndk to "solve" the issue. Now I don't know if it's a real solution. NB the problem started *after* switching  ID.

Answer (score 1):

If You have client 8.5.* and higher - profiles cached while client is open, this solved by restart client only.

Comment: Very old issue, I dont't remember details, but see @FrantisekKossuth comment.